# Marketo REST API token keeps expiring

Tags: marketo

I followed the [Quick Start Guide](http://developers.marketo.com/blog/quick-start-guide-for-marketo-rest-api/) on Marketo's site for their REST API. This went well. I was able to get a successful response from their website.

Request:

```
curl https://ABC-DEF-123.mktorest.com/rest/v1/lists.json?access_token=123:ab
```

Response:

```
{"requestId":"123#abcf7aff","result":[],"success":true}
```

However, when I tried the same request the next day, I received:

```
{"requestId":"123#abc6731ab6f","success":false,"errors":[{"code":"601","message":"Access token invalid"}]}
```

I logged into the Marketo admin and noticed that the token I copied and pasted out of the dialog box was different. I tried this new one and it worked.

(This is taken from the guide)

[image: Marketo Token Dialog]

I came across another guide on their site that describes a different authentication process. [Marketo Authentication Guide](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/authentication/)

This guide mentions the token that is returned from the API endpoint has an expiration so I suspect that all Marketo tokens expire (or I need to disable this). However, I have not been able to successfully make requests to this endpoint with my client ID and client secret.

Request:

```
curl https://ABC-DEF-123.mktorest.com/identity/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=ACLIENTID&client_secret=ACLIENTSECRET
```

Response:

```
{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"}
```

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the Marketo REST API tokens expire in around 15 minutes from generation, so you'll need to re-request a token

Answer (score 5):

REST API tokens expire. So you typically will need to request a token for each session.

from your specific installed URL, like: MARKETOURL/identity/oauth/tokengrant_type=client_credentials&client_id=abc&client_secret=xyz

Which will result in (example):

```
{
"access_token": "1234",
"token_type": "bearer",
"expires_in": 3599,
"scope": "email@email.com"
}
```

You will need to start out your sessions with this request to do subsequent calls. I have code that runs this first and then requests a new token if it expires. The expires_in field is in seconds.

Source: http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to figure out why my curl requests were failing, but I was able to successfully call the Marketo API with [mrkt](https://github.com/raszi/mrkt), a Ruby Gem for Marketo.

I've looked through the logs of what the gem is generating for requests and they appear to be exactly the same. But at least I now successfully calling Marketo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use following sequences.

```
grant_type=  client_credentials
client_id =you will get Marketo admin where you generate token
client_secret=you will get Marketo admin where you generate token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8



GET <Identity URL>/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<Client Id>&client_secret=<Client Secret>
```

Comment: It's better to [add more context/explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) around code (as opposed to just having a code-only answer) as that makes the answer more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your first call failed because your token expires every hour currently, according to Marketo's docs.

Your curl call to get a new token failed because curl (or something) was stripping off the auth arguments. Try wrapping the url in quotes.

```
curl "https://ABC-DEF-123.mktorest.com/identity/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=ACLIENTID&client_secret=ACLIENTSECRET"
```

You can get more information about what curl is sending with the `-v` flag. Running this would have given you enough information to at least know that your entire url wasn't being passed down to the request.

```
curl -v https://ABC-DEF-123.mktorest.com/identity/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=ACLIENTID&client_secret=ACLIENTSECRET
```